# Как протестить пропускную способность локальной сети?

Tags: сеть, администрирование

Для этого, как я понимаю, необходимо клиент-серверное приложение, генерирующее TCP, UDP, ICMP и т.д. траффик и собирающее статистику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Iperf](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) - кроссплатформенная консольная клиент-серверная программа — генератор TCP и UDP трафика для тестирования пропускной способности сети.

Comment: Давно его пытался скачать, сайт все был недоступен. Сейчас получилось :)